# git - как изменить кодировку коммита

Tags: git, кодировка, git-commit

В центральный git-репозиторий попал коммит с некорректной кодировкой и теперь при получении коммита на linux происходит конфликт на этапе слияния изменений, как исправить кодировку коммита?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исправить кодировку коммита можно следующим способом:

```
$ git filter-branch -f --commit-filter '
author_type=$( echo $GIT_AUTHOR_NAME | file -b --mime-encoding - )
author=$( echo $GIT_AUTHOR_NAME | iconv -f $author_type -t UTF-8 )
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=$author

committer_type=$( echo $GIT_COMMITTER_NAME | file -b --mime-encoding - )
committer=$( echo $GIT_COMMITTER_NAME | iconv -f $committer_type -t UTF-8 )
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=$committer

git commit-tree "$@";' --msg-filter '
cat > .commitmsg
type=$(cat .commitmsg|file -b --mime-encoding -)
cat .commitmsg|iconv -f $type -t UTF-8
' HEAD

$ rm -f .commitmsg
```

Так же рекомендую ознакомиться с [документацией](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit). Ближе к концу описываются некоторые детали работы с кодировкой гитом.

Comment: Ох, гитовая магия )

Comment: @NickVolynkin гит и не на такое способен. Можно например сделать так, что бы гит периодически сам собирал исходники из центрального репозитория :)

Comment: что значит «собирал» — делал pull или выполнял сборку проекта? Периодически это по хуку или по таймеру?

Comment: Периодический pull по таймеру :)

Comment: заходите в чат. Хочу подробнее расспросить, но комментарии для этого неудобны. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26116/git--ru-so